# Error when requesting sqlite db with react native

Tags: react-native, sqlite

I just started react native with sqlite.
I have a function requesting my db but i dont get anything from it, i have an error but i dont know how to fix it
I think i have a problem when i try to connect to my db

Here is the part of my code i'm talking about:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { StatusBar,StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View, Button, Range } from 'react-native';
import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite';
import Slider from '@react-native-community/slider'

const db = SQLite.openDatabase('database.db');


 

export default function App() {


  const [range, setRange]= useState(Number);
  const [valeurdB, setValeurdB]= useState(Number);

  const setdB= () => {
    db.transaction(txn =>
      txn.executeSql('UPDATE settings SET number=? WHERE title == \'new\';',
      [range],
      (txn, res)=> {
        console.log("db updated")
      },
      error=>{ console.log('Error on  set ' + error.message) }
      )
    )
  
  }
```

Here is what i get:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40kbq.png)

And my architecture :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXBUN.png)

Comment: try to log the error not the error.message, maybe it gives you more meaningful info.

Comment: What is the error? Have you performed a search on that error?

Comment: I found my mistake, error callback function needed 2 parameters: in my cas txn and error!